# Error with database context

Tags: android, sqlite, global-variables, android-context

Hello I want to make a database as global instance, so I can reach from different activities ( I have one activity for add contact, another one to view contact and another one to delete contact...).

So my GlobalInstance should be like:

```
package com.example.informacion;

import android.content.Context;

public class BaseDatosGlobal {

    public BaseDatosContactos miAgenda;

    private BaseDatosGlobal() {
        miAgenda = new BaseDatosContactos(getApplicationContext());
      }


    private static BaseDatosGlobal instance;

      public static BaseDatosGlobal getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) instance = new BaseDatosGlobal();
        return instance;
      }
}
```

I want `miAgenda` to be the name of the database accessed from any activity. The problem is the context. I should create `miAgenda= new BaseDatosContactos(getApplicationContext());` but I cant because eclipse gives me an error. The method `getAplicationContext()` is undefined for the type `BaseDatosGlobal`.

So I can use `miAgenda.insertarcontacto(....)` or `miAgenda.borrarContacto` or whatever from any place.

Any help or ideas are welcome

My BaseDatosContatos is like:

```
   public class BaseDatosContactos extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        private static final int VERSION_BASEDATOS = 1;

        // Nombre de nuestro archivo de base de datos
        private static final String NOMBRE_BASEDATOS = "contactos.db";

        // Sentencia SQL para la creación de una tabla
        private static final String TABLA_CONTACTOS = "CREATE TABLE contactos" +  
                "(email TEXT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL, nombre TEXT, telefono TEXT, direccion TEXT, miembrofacebook INT, miembrotwitter INT, miembrogoogle INT, miembrolinkedin INT, sexo INT, tipocontacto TEXT, imagen INT)";

        public BaseDatosContactos(Context context) {
            super(context, NOMBRE_BASEDATOS, null, VERSION_BASEDATOS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             db.execSQL(TABLA_CONTACTOS);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLA_CONTACTOS);
             onCreate(db);
        }

        public void insertarContacto (String email, String nombre, String telefono, String direccion, int miembrofacebook, int miembrotwitter, int miembrogoogle, int miembrolinkedin, int sexo, String tipocontacto, int imagen){
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            if (db != null) {
                ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
                valores.put("email", email);
                valores.put("nombre", nombre);
                valores.put("telefono", telefono);
                valores.put("direccion", direccion);
                valores.put("miembrofacebook", miembrofacebook);
                valores.put("miembrotwitter", miembrotwitter);
                valores.put("miembrogoogle", miembrogoogle);
                valores.put("miembrolinkedin", miembrolinkedin);
                valores.put("sexo", sexo);
                valores.put("tipocontacto", tipocontacto);
                valores.put("imagen", imagen);
                db.insert("contactos", null, valores);
            }
            db.close();   
        }

    //Creo un insertarcontacto propio pasandole un contacto
        public void insertarContacto ( contactoAgenda contacto){
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            if (db != null) {
                ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
                valores.put("email", contacto.getMail());
                valores.put("nombre", contacto.getNombre());
                valores.put("telefono", contacto.getTelefono());
                valores.put("direccion", contacto.getDireccion());
                valores.put("miembrofacebook", contacto.isMiembroFacebook());
                valores.put("miembrotwitter", contacto.isMiembroTwitter());
                valores.put("miembrogoogle", contacto.isMiembroGoogle());
                valores.put("miembrolinkedin", contacto.isMiembroLinnkedin());
                valores.put("sexo", contacto.isSexo());
                valores.put("tipocontacto", contacto.getTipoContacto());
                valores.put("imagen", contacto.getDrawableImageID());
                db.insert("contactos", null, valores);
            }
            db.close();   
        }

        public void modificarContacto(String email, String nombre, String telefono, String direccion, int miembrofacebook, int miembrotwitter, int miembrogoogle, int miembrolinkedin, int sexo, String tipocontacto, int imagen){
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("email", email);
            valores.put("nombre", nombre);
            valores.put("telefono", telefono);
            valores.put("direccion", direccion);
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", miembrofacebook);
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", miembrotwitter);
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", miembrogoogle);
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", miembrolinkedin);
            valores.put("sexo", sexo);
            valores.put("tipocontacto", tipocontacto);
            valores.put("imagen", imagen);
            db.update("contactos", valores, "email=" + email, null);
            //db.update("contactos", valores, "_id=" + id, null);
            db.close();   
        }

        public void modificarContacto(contactoAgenda contacto){

            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
            valores.put("email", contacto.getMail());
            valores.put("nombre", contacto.getNombre());
            valores.put("telefono", contacto.getTelefono());
            valores.put("direccion", contacto.getDireccion());
            valores.put("miembrofacebook", contacto.isMiembroFacebook());
            valores.put("miembrotwitter", contacto.isMiembroTwitter());
            valores.put("miembrogoogle", contacto.isMiembroGoogle());
            valores.put("miembrolinkedin", contacto.isMiembroLinnkedin());
            valores.put("sexo", contacto.isSexo());
            valores.put("tipocontacto", contacto.getTipoContacto());
            valores.put("imagen", contacto.getDrawableImageID());
            db.update("contactos", valores, "email=" + contacto.getMail(), null);
            db.close();   
        }



        public void borrarContacto(String email) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("contactos", "email=" + email, null);
            db.close();  
        }

        public void borrarContacto( contactoAgenda contacto) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("contactos", "email=" + contacto.getMail(), null);
            db.close();  
        }


        public contactoAgenda recuperarContacto(String email) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            String[] valores_recuperar = {"email", "nombre", "telefono","direccion","miembrofacebook","miembrotwitter","miembrogoogle","miembrolinkedin","sexo","tipocontacto","imagen"};   
            Cursor c = db.query("contactos", valores_recuperar, "email=" + email, null, null, null, null,null);
            if(c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
            }
            contactoAgenda contactos = new contactoAgenda(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3),c.getInt(4), c.getInt(5), c.getInt(6), c.getInt(7),c.getInt(8), c.getString(9), c.getInt(10));
            db.close();
            c.close();
            return contactos;
        }


        public ArrayList<contactoAgenda> recuperarTodosContactos() {
            SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
            ArrayList<contactoAgenda> lista_contactos = new ArrayList<contactoAgenda>();
            String[] valores_recuperar = {"email", "nombre", "telefono","direccion","miembrofacebook","miembrotwitter","miembrogoogle","miembrolinkedin","sexo","tipocontacto","imagen"};
            Cursor c = db.query("contactos", valores_recuperar, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            do {
                contactoAgenda contactos = new contactoAgenda(c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getString(2), c.getString(3),c.getInt(4), c.getInt(5), c.getInt(6), c.getInt(7),c.getInt(8), c.getString(9), c.getInt(10));
                lista_contactos.add(contactos);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
            db.close();
            c.close();
            return lista_contactos;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant access `getApplicationContext()` directly in **BaseDatosGlobal** class. You can access `getApplicationContext()` in `Activity`.

and for that make one argument `constructor` in your `BaseDatosGlobal` class and pass **context** as a argument like so,

```
  private Context mCon;

  private BaseDatosGlobal(Context con) { 
    this.mCon=con;
  }
```

Now called this in `Activity` like

```
BaseDatosGlobal BSA=new BaseDatosGlobal(getAppplicationContext());
```

Comment: Shouldnt i call BaseDatosGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.insertarContacto(contactoActual);  for example from any activity ??

Comment: @EduardoGutiérrez but for accessing `database` you need `context` in class `BaseDatosContactos` for `Open` and `Close` DB

Comment: @M D yes but once i put your solution... the way to access miAgenda could be of the style BaseDatosGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.insertarContacto(contactoActual); ??  Because as you point BaseDatosGlobal BSA=new BaseDatosGlobal(getAppplicationContext()); then i need to create a new BaseDatosGlobal in every activity.... If i understand this the right way....

Comment: you could keep a static approach, but still you have to pass the Context to static "factory" method

Comment: @M D infact our answers are almost identical :)

Comment: Sorry but it gives me error that BaseDatosContactos() needs a context to create....   public class BaseDatosGlobal {

 public BaseDatosContactos miAgenda;
 private Context mCon;

 private BaseDatosGlobal() {
     
   }
 
 private BaseDatosGlobal(Context con) { 
     this.mCon=con;
     miAgenda = new BaseDatosContactos();
   }


 private static BaseDatosGlobal instance;

   public static BaseDatosGlobal getInstance() {
     if (instance == null) instance = new BaseDatosGlobal();
     return instance;
   }
}

Comment: @Shine @M D i ve answered myself because it doesnt work... The way you recommend, then i cant see  any difference between BaseDatosGlobal and BaseDatosContactos.... ( i'd have to create a new instance BaseDatosGlobal every activity).... if so i create a BaseDatosContactos every activity and i dont need any global instance....Correct me if im wrong Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the Context to BaseDatosContatos constructor and add it as a field:

```
private BaseDatosGlobal(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    miAgenda = new BaseDatosContactos();
  }
```

There are other solutions, this being the easiest. Of course you can't call `getApplicationContext()` since your class isn't extending Activity

Comment: Shouldnt i call BaseDatosGlobal.getInstance().miAgenda.insertarContacto(contactoActual); for example from any activity ?? Thanks

Comment: yes, but you actually need to pass the Context anyway...Another example could then be: BaseDatosGlobal.getInstance(context).miAgenda.insertarContacto(contactoActual);